# How to replace 'k' or 'm' with 000s from object column in dataframe and replace non number values?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a df that looks like this, dtype is object can not cast to int or float:

```
col1
100
100k
100k-100m
10m
50
```

How do I replace the `k` with `000` and the `m` with `000000` within this column that is type object?

Furthermore, once I can replace the `k` or `m` how do I replace everything that is not a number with nothing?

New df should look like this(not the blank space):

```
col1
100
100000

10000000
50
```

Tried this code:

```
 df.col1 = (df.col1.replace(r'[KM]+$', '', regex=True).astype(float) * \
          df.col1.str.extract(r'[\d\.]+([KM]+)', expand=False)
             .fillna(1)
             .replace(['K','M'], [10**3, 10**6]).astype(int))
```

but columns have to be float

Comment: What should `100k-100m` become?

Comment: @user3483203 I want to replace it with nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Similarly to @user3483203, but with `str.translate` rather than `str.replace`

```
df['col1'] = df.col1.str.translate(str.maketrans({'k':'000','m':'000000'}))
>>> df
               col1
0               100
1            100000
2  100000-100000000
3          10000000
4                50

# df['col1'] = pd.to_numeric(df.col1.str.translate(str.maketrans({'k':'000','m':'000000'})),errors='coerce')

#          col1
# 0       100.0
# 1    100000.0
# 2         NaN
# 3  10000000.0
# 4        50.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Creating a mapping dictionary and use `str.replace`:

```
dct = {'k': '000', 'm': '000000'}

df.col1.str.replace(r'|'.join(dct.keys()), lambda x: dct[x.group()])
```

```
0                 100
1              100000
2    100000-100000000
3            10000000
4                  50
Name: col1, dtype: object
```

If you want to remove the third row instead of replace, like in your output:

```
(pd.to_numeric(df.col1.str.replace(r'|'.join(dct.keys()),
    lambda x: dct[x.group()]), errors='coerce'))
```

```
0         100.0
1      100000.0
2           NaN
3    10000000.0
4          50.0
Name: col1, dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I came up with. Let me know what you think. I did the extra thing of removing the decimal places.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.Series(['100','100k','100k-100m','10m','50'])

df = df.str.replace('k', '000', regex=True)
df = df.str.replace('m', '000000', regex=True)
df = pd.to_numeric(df, errors='coerce')
df = df.apply(str).str.split('.', expand=True).iloc[ : , 0 ]

print(df)
```